# textview cutting off a letter in android

Tags: android

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24856/Screenshots/android/cutoff.png]

this is a screen shot from my android. the text is "asd". however the "d" is slightly cut off. here is the relevant view:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stuff"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/other_stuff"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
```

any idea as to what is causing this ?

Comment: paste all xml file here pls, not just of textview.

Comment: did you try removing the padding? (if it works just change it to margin)

Comment: this is still happening in 2019. How is this not fixed yet? Surely it's a bug. wrap_content should know how to deal with italic text.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ended up with a hacky solution which is adding a white space after the last italicized character

Comment: For posterity, I'll note my experiences. This occurred with an italic font on multiple devices (even up to Jellybean). Changing the padding property did nothing. Only two hacky things worked: (1) setting a fixed width wider than it needs and (2) programmatically adding a space at the end like so: tv.setText(tv.getText() + " ");

Comment: For anyone still struggling with this, I have created a general method to solve this with multiple lines. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218468/4420543

Answer (score 9):

Ok this is pretty strange but I changed from `android:maxLines="1"` to `android:singleLine="true"` and now the text is not getting cut off.

Comment: *Note: android:singleLine is deprecated

Comment: I know that `android:singleLine` is deprecated, however in some instances, using `android:maxLines="1"` will cause text to get cut off.  This is clearly a bug.

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by Android setting the `TextView` clipping rectangle for standard text and you using italic text. Italic text leans to the right, outside of the text bounds. For some reason Android does not account for this.

To prevent this, you can force a `TextView` to draw outside of its bounds by giving it a text shadow. If you set the shadow color to transparent, the result is simply un-clipped text. Add these to your `TextView`:

```
android:shadowColor="#00FFFFFF"
android:shadowDx="48"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="1"
```

Also, if this doesn't work, try setting `android:clipChildren=false` on the parent layout.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with setting the width of TextView to fill_parent instead of wrap_content...

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution: 
Format textview and measure. After that set width of textview with 1 pixel add to the width measured.

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Text blah blah");
    textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
    textView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(textView.getMeasuredWidth() + 1, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Working for me. Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down the source of the error try setting `android:letterSpacing="0"` This was the reason for cut off letters in my case. Another hint for too much letter spacing is that the cut off part get bigger when the text has more letters in it.

Comment: I was setting `letterSpacing` to 0.01 and it caused the issue. Looks like a bug in `TextView`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it if the issue is caused by the letterSpacing and we can't change it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue would not occur if you were not using italic text. I'd test that out first, and if using non-italic text renders it correctly, then it looks like a rendering issue, that would need working around with extra padding in the TextView to allow space for the italic letters.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is, the italic property. You have to set a particular width for your textview.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create custom TextView that will use for example this font (cause in fact this is a problem with *italic* type):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
setTypeface(tf);
```

More details [here](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI/blob/master/library/src/com/afollestad/cardsui/LightItalicTextView.java).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but with `EditText` when used some fonts. My solution works also with `TextView`:

1. Use padding
2. As `TextView` using `Canvas.clipRect(float, float, float, float)` in `onDraw` method to crop - create custom `Canvas` class and override this method (leave it empty).
3. Next сreate custom `TextView` and override two methods `onSizeChanged` and `onDraw`.

In `onSizeChanged` create bitmap with the size of `TextView` and our custom `Canvas`.

In `onDraw` first draw in bitmap by passing our custom `Canvas` to method super.onDraw. After that draw bitmap to target сanvas.

More detailed in my answer to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848612/8816298)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
textview.setShadowLayer(25f, 0f, 0f, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution** If you dont want to show ... to the end of text and want to show the complete text irrespective of number of lines than just add padding bottom 5dp to the textview.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

istead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```