# Android - TextView wrap_content not working when number text

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, android-wrap-content

My device has not set a custom font, so the font of the app is supposed to follow the device setting font.

When applying custom font, the width of the textview was found to be cut, so I left it as wrap_content, but it didn't work properly. (Default font set wrap_contetnt works well)

The code is as below, and the number is cut like this.
Help anyone! Help me!

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: You image is not working

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Sorry,,,, Image link Here : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52276038/121281541-03307100-c913-11eb-84b8-7b6c10b3106f.png

Comment: can you share the codes for that layout?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Sorry, But the codes for that layout just set TextView In. ConstraintLayout, And TextView Text Size set DP

Comment: You said inside the `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yes!

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I reslove this issue through the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074858/android-textview-text-get-cut-off-on-the-sides-with-custom-font

Comment: I resolve this issue through the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074858/android-textview-text-get-cut-off-on-the-sides-with-custom-font